# C++: error: ‘Vector’ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am writing two templated classes (for academic reasons):

1. 'class Vector', which mimics a C++ vector using a dynamic array.
2. 'class Set', which creates a set using a vector object.

Vector.cpp -

```
#ifndef __CS_VECTOR_H_
#define __CS_VECTOR_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include "Set.cpp"

template <class Type>
class Vector
{

    public:
        Vector(unsigned int capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        Vector(const Vector<Type>& rhs);
        ~Vector();
        unsigned int capacity() const; 
        unsigned int size() const; 
        bool empty() const; 
        void push_back(const Type& data); 
        bool remove(const Type& data); 
        void clear(); 
        bool at(unsigned int pos, Type& data) const;
        int get_array_size() const;
        Type& operator[](unsigned int pos) const;
        Vector& operator=(const Vector& rhs);

    private:
        static const unsigned int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 3;
        void generate_larger_array(unsigned int capacity);
        int array_size_ = 0;
        int array_capacity_;
        Type *array_;

}; 

//Function definitions here.
//#include "Set.cpp"
#endif
```

Set.cpp -

```
#ifndef __CS_SET_H_
#define __CS_SET_H_

#include "Vector.cpp"

template <class Comparable>
class Set
{
    public:
        unsigned int size() const; 
        bool empty() const; 
        bool contains(const Comparable& data) const; 
        bool insert(const Comparable& data); 
        bool remove(const Comparable& data); 
        void clear();
        int get_size();
    private:
        int element_;
        Vector<Comparable> set_;

}; 

//Function definitions here

//#include "Vector.cpp"
#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Set.cpp"
#include "Vector.cpp"
```

When I compile my code, I receive an error telling me:

```
error: ‘Vector’ does not name a type Vector<Comparable> set_;
```

When declaring my set_ object in Set.

These are both cpp files that are included into a file main.cpp. The set cpp file does contain the #include vector.cpp and vice versa

main.cpp just has code that tests the class functionality. I receive this error when attempting to compile either the main.cpp file. The main.cpp file is written by my instructor, so I am not entirely sure I should post it here.

Comment: Where are your header files? If all you have is what you posted, then when the compiler is compiling Set.cpp, it has no way of knowing that Vector exists.

Comment: @JosephSible Sorry, these are header files. I edited the original post.

Comment: Set.h needs to include Vector.h. Also, you should post your .cpp files as well then.

Comment: Can you please post all the portions of the Set.h, including how you have included the Vector.h. Also where are you placing the implementations of all the functions?

Comment: are Set.h and Vector.h both in the same directory?  If not, and you're including them with double-quotes, you need to give the relative path.

Comment: you need to `#include "Vector.h"` in `Set.h` and then `#include "Set.h"` in main.cpp. Also don't forget to have include guards for your header files.